# How to Implement Typeorm Entity Array of Object

Tags: postgresql, orm, nestjs, typeorm

I want to achieve this output:

```js
{
  .....,
  dependants: [{name: 'john', age: 29},{name: 'doe', age: 17}]
}
```

I have an entity like this:

```js
class PartnerStaff extends BaseEntity {
  constructor(
    id: string,
    company: string,
    branch: string,
    dependants: DependantDto[],
  ) {
    super();
    this.staffId = id;
    this.company = company;
    this.branch = branch;
    this.dependants = dependants;
  }

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  id!: number;

  @Column({
    unique: true,
    nullable: true,
  })
  staffId!: string;

  @Column({
    nullable: true,
    name: 'company',
  })
  company!: string;

  @Column()
  branch!: string;

  @Column('json', {nullable: true})
  dependants?: DependantDto[];
}
```

And my dependants dto:

```js
class DependantDto {
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty({ message: 'dependant name is required' })
  readonly name!: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty({ message: 'dependant age is required' })
  readonly age!: number;
}
```

I am getting `dependants: ['string']` on swagger.

I have tried these but still not working...

```js
@Column('jsonb', {nullable: true})

@Column({type: 'array', nullable: true})
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it this way....

```
@Column({type: 'json'})
dependants: DependantsDto[];
```

Then in my PartnerStaffDto, I did ...

```
@IsOptional()
@ApiModelProperty({
isArray: true
})
dependants: DependantsDto[];
```

So now I get what i was expecting ealier `dependants: [{name: '', age: 0}]`